# usage cases for 失礼します?

Tags: meaning, usage

I was listening a conversation where a guy said そろそろ 失礼します。
I also heard inflections like 失礼しました。

> Google translate : 失礼します == Excuse me.
>   is it correct ?

What is the proper meaning and usage cases for  失礼します ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

失礼 is used in many situations.
It can be used as an apology, which is the original meaning of the word.
But it can also be used as a greeting when entering or leaving a room or a place.
It is very common for workers to leave the workplace by greeting the other co-coworkers with
お先に失礼します。(o-saki ni shitsurei shimasu)

It can also be used as a greeting when finishing a phone conversation.

It can be used just like in English to start a conversation:
失礼ですが... (excuse me...)

http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/98858/meaning/m0u/
https://careerpark.jp/77267

Comment: My colleagues say お先に失礼します everyday before leaving office. Now I understood. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, in English "greeting" is only used for words used when meeting, not parting. I'm not sure if there's a one-word term for parting words in English.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to use it.
失礼 means rude.

> そろそろ 失礼します。

Probably means

> "I will be leaving soon"

It is used a lot when you finish your day at work for example.
I guess in a way it means that you will do the rudeness of leaving before the others.

> 失礼しました

means

> I did something rude

And can be used in many ways. For example, you could say it after you got corrected after saying something wrong making a mistake.